# Angular 4 - Select default value in dropdown [Reactive Forms]

Tags: angular

In Angular 4, I have the following configuration defined in a json config file.

```
 countries: ['USA', 'UK', 'Canada'];
 default: 'UK'
```

I need to display these in a dropdown using Reactive module.

Here is the code to do this (ts)

```
countries: string[] = [];
default: string;
...
this.countries = config.countries;
this.default = config.default;
```

html

```
<select id="country" formControlName="country"  >
 <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c" >{{ c }}</option>
</select>
```

This does the job and displays the countries in a drop down.
However, I also need to select a country by default and the default country comes from the 'default' key defined in json.

So, I tried doing something like this

{{ c }}

However, this does not work. By default an empty value if selected.

How can I make sure that a predefined value is selected by default?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try like this :

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="countryForm">
    <select id="country" formControlName="country">
        <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{ c }}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class Component {

    countries: string[] = ['USA', 'UK', 'Canada'];
    default: string = 'UK';

    countryForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
        this.countryForm = new FormGroup({
            country: new FormControl(null);
        });
        this.countryForm.controls['country'].setValue(this.default, {onlySelf: true});
    }
}
```

Comment: Can [(ngModel)] be used when using Reactive Forms.

Comment: One followup question. What does '{onlySelf: true}' imply?

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602837/angular-2-formcontrol-setvalue-onlyself-parameter?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set the default value in the constructor for the new FormControl?

Answer (score 19):

In Reactive forms. Binding can be done in the component file and usage of ngValue. For more details please go through the following link

https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <select formControlName="state">
        <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state">
          {{ state.abbrev }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </form>

       <p>Form value: {{ form.value | json }}</p> 
       <!-- {state: {name: 'New York', abbrev: 'NY'} } -->
    `,
})
export class ReactiveSelectComp {
  states = [
    {name: 'Arizona', abbrev: 'AZ'},
    {name: 'California', abbrev: 'CA'},
    {name: 'Colorado', abbrev: 'CO'},
    {name: 'New York', abbrev: 'NY'},
    {name: 'Pennsylvania', abbrev: 'PA'},
  ];

  form = new FormGroup({
    state: new FormControl(this.states[3]),
  });
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I was struggling and Found this Easy and Effective way from `IntelliJ IDEA` suggestion

```
<select id="country" formControlName="country"  >
  <option [defaultSelected]=true [value]="default" >{{default}}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c" >{{ c }}</option>
</select>
```

And On your ts file assign the values

```
 countries = ['USA', 'UK', 'Canada'];
 default = 'UK'
```

Just make sure your formControlName accepts string, because you already assigned it as a string.

Comment: easy way to make it selected value

Answer (score 5):

In your component -

Make sure to initialize the formControl name **country** with a value.

For instance:
Assuming that your form group name is **myForm** and **_fb** is FormBuilder instance then,

```
....
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
  country:[this.default]
})
```

and also try replacing **[value]** with **[ngValue]**.

**EDIT 1**: If you are unable to initialize the value when declaring then set the value when you have the value like this.

```
this.myForm.controls.country.controls.setValue(this.country)
```

Comment: [value] or [ngValue] gives the same result. Also, as per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000189/angular-4-find-selected-value-in-dropdown/47002742#47002742 it's suggested to use [value] from string.

Comment: Can't initialize the default value while initializing a form as this value is fetched much after the form is initialized. So, there are multiple such configs defined, and based on some user inputs/selection a specific set of configs are loaded.

Comment: I have edited my answer, check if its working for you

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a new property (ex:selectedCountry)  and should use it in `[(ngModel)]` and further in component file assign `default` value to it.

In your_component_file.ts

```
this.selectedCountry = default;
```

In your_component_template.html

```
<select id="country" formControlName="country" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
 <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c" >{{ c }}</option>
</select>
```

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XRr0eHevenilxejNwDEx?p=preview)

Comment: I am using Reactive module. Can [(ngModel)] be used with that?

Comment: ideally `[(ngModel)]` should not be used with `reactive forms`, while answering I didn't notice reactive form:) ., anyway please [check this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766029/angular2-reactive-forms-set-default-value-for-form-fields-with-dropdown)

Comment: You can't use ngmodel with reactive forms like that anymore since Angular 7.

Answer (score 4):

As option, if you need just default text in dropdown without default value, try add `<option disabled value="null">default text here</option>` like this:

```html
<select id="country" formControlName="country">
 <option disabled value="null">default text here</option>
 <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c" >{{ c }}</option>
</select>
```

In Chrome and Firefox works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the patch function for setting defaults with some of the values in your form group.

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="countryForm">
    <select id="country" formControlName="country">
        <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{ c }}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class Component implements OnInit{

    countries: string[] = ['USA', 'UK', 'Canada'];
    default: string = 'UK';

    countryForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() {

        this.countryForm.controls['country'].setValue(this.default, {onlySelf: true});
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.countryForm = new FormGroup({
      'country': new FormControl(null)
    }); 

    this.countryForm.patchValue({
      'country': default
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option [defaultSelected]="condition"> Default option here value</option>
```

condition must be true to select the input by default

To select for eg UK by default, we need to name the option et make the condition like this

```
<option [defaultSelected]="inputName.value==='UK' " #inputName> Default value </option>
```

to select UK by default and you must add the value attribute or use

```
<option [defaultSelected]="inputName.text==='UK' " #inputName> Default value </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Component:   `Default: string = '-1';`
If dynamic then call this in your method or if static then call this inside constructor
`this.XYZFormGroup.controls['ABCList'].setValue(this.Default, {onlySelf: true});` 
HTML: `<option value="-1">--Select a member--</option>`