# How to set default value on select in a dynamic select component angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a dynamic `select` component for my application. This component would be used in various forms throughout my application. In some cases, there may be some predefined value that may be provided to the `select`, in which case the value would be selected as default by the drop-down. In order to achieve this functionality I have looked over SO and found various questions that answer this problem, but are using `NgModule` as a directive for adding default value, whereas I am using `formControlName` for my component. I have tried a solution myself (code added below) but it doesn't seem to be working. I am reluctant to use `ngModule` with `formControlName` because the feature is deprecated in Angular 6 (the version I am using). How do I achieve the functionality?

**component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="group">
  <select id="{{ id }}" formControlName="{{ formControlName }}" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled selected>{{placeholder}}</option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of data" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
/**
* This class is used to create a generic dropdown component. Population is done on runtime
*/
export class DropdownComponent{
  /**
  * Define FormGroup
  */
  @Input() group: FormGroup;

  /**
  * Define formControlName
  */
  @Input() formControlName: string;

  /**
  * Define id
  */
  @Input() id: string;

  /**
  * Define data
  */
  @Input() data: any;

  /**
  * Define placeholder
  */
  @Input() placeholder: string;

  /**
  * For any predefined value being passed
  */
  @Input() predefined: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

**what I tried (ts file remained the same)**

```
<div [formGroup]="group">
  <select id="{{ id }}" formControlName="{{ formControlName }}" class="form-control">
    <ng-template *ngIf="predefined !== undefined; else default">
      <option *ngFor="let item of data" [selected]="item.id === predefined">{{item.name}}</option>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #default>
      <option value="" disabled selected>{{placeholder}}</option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of data" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
    </ng-template>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: why not using reactive form?

Comment: @brk could you please explain?\

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011521/angular-4-select-default-value-in-dropdown-reactive-forms/47011771), but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to cater the problem, the solution was to define a method in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook, which extracted the entire object an inserted into the template. The lifecycle hook sets a particular variable called selection and sets to the `formControl`:

```
selection: any

ngOnInit() {
    if (this.predefined !== undefined) {
      let index = Object.keys(this.data);
      var self = this;
      index.forEach(function(i) {
        Object.keys(self.data[i]).some(function(k) {
          if (self.data[i][k] === self.predefined) {
            self.selection = self.data[i];
            return self.data[i][k];
          }
        }
        )
      });
      this.group.controls[this.formControlName].setValue(this.selection.id, { onlySelf: true });
    }
  }
```

The template didn't need any modification like I did in the question's update, so reverted to the previous:

```
<div [formGroup]="group">
  <select id="{{ id }}" formControlName="{{ formControlName }}" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled selected>{{placeholder}}</option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of data" [(ngValue)]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

So if you want to provide any default values to the select statement you can do something like below,

Let's say I have this array of object in .ts

```
 Sports = [
 {
    "name": "running",
    "value" : "0"
 },
 {
    "name": "triathlon",
    "value" : "1"
 }
]
```

You can set the default value for the select statement in html like below,

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="get($event.target.value)">
   <option [value]="null" hidden>
      Select
   </option>
   <option *ngFor="let sport of Sports" [value]="sport.value">
      {{sport.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```