# how can I apply the select directive to the first option generated by a *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, ngfor

I have a select whose `options` are generated for the data returned by an HTTP request in the `ngOninit` hook.

it looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.documentosService.buscaParametros(this.request).subscribe(res => {
    this.tipoDocumento = res["general"];

  }
```

this is the HTML code:

```
   <select class="form-control pv-0" formControlName="tipoFactura" name="tipoFactura">    
        <option *ngFor="let documento of tipoDocumento">
          {{documento.par_deslargo01}}</option>
      </select>
```

If it wasn't generated dynamically I could just write the `selected` directive to the first `option` element, but in this case I don't know how to achieve it. I need that when the component first load the first option is selected.

How could achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 - Select default value in dropdown \[Reactive Forms\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011521/angular-4-select-default-value-in-dropdown-reactive-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer the question posed, ngFor exposes a number of helpful template variables, among them is "first" which which is true if you're on the first item, false otherwise:

```
<option *ngFor="let documento of tipoDocumento; let first" [selected]="first">
      {{documento.par_deslargo01}}</option>
```

also last, index, even and odd are offered.

but, since you're using reactive forms, the recommended method is to skip all that and set the form control value:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.documentosService.buscaParametros(this.request).subscribe(res => {
    this.tipoDocumento = res["general"];
    this.form.get('tipoFactura').setValue(this.tipoDocumento[0].par_deslargo01)
    // not sure what your form variable really is
  }
}
```

this will automatically select that value in your list of options

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. you can do something like this.

```
<select class="form-control pv-0" formControlName="tipoFactura" name="tipoFactura">    
        <option *ngFor="let documento of tipoDocumento; let i = index" [selected]="i === 0">
          {{documento.par_deslargo01}}</option>
</select>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2dvtu8)**

> **Update - Using Reacting Forms**

As you are using [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) you can use features of reactive forms to do what you want. In your case you can set selected `option` to `select` as below.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select formControlName="mySelect">
    <option *ngFor="let coutry of countries" [value]="coutry">{{coutry}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
  countries: any = ['Sri Lanka', 'USA', 'UK', 'Australia'];
  selectedCoutry = 'Australia';

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {

    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      mySelect: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.get('mySelect').setValue(this.selectedCoutry);
  }
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wej8c4)**