# Default value not selected after 'Select' options are passed as Input

Tags: angular

My select control is as below

```
    <select formControlName="productType">
        <option *ngFor="let option of optionsArray; let i = index"
                [selected]="i===0">
            {{ option.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

In my ts file the optionsArray is a property

```
@Input( 'options'):IMyOption[]

get optionsArray(): IMyOption[] {
    return Object.values( this.options );
}
```

The options is a input from parent component. All I want is to the select the first item but is always blank. The options are populated from the parent correctly. How can I get [selected] to work? Please help.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 - Select default value in dropdown \[Reactive Forms\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011521/angular-4-select-default-value-in-dropdown-reactive-forms)

Comment: I know setting the value in constructor will work - but I do not know the value as its a input array

Comment: @user2837961 can't you just check when the array is initially loaded and set it to the first element in the array?

Comment: Yes I have done that

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<select formControlName="productType">
    <option *ngFor="let option of optionsArray; let i = index"
            [selected]="i===0 ? 'true': ''">
        {{ option.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: No - unfortunately not

Comment: Inspect the final select and check if the first element has the attribute `selected=selected`

Comment: No - there is no option of 'selected' in dev tools

Comment: Try changing "selected" for true as modified, I hava made a example on Stackblitz following your code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quyaec?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You are right. Work when you have options in OnInit but does not if the options are passed in @Input