# Why can't I mark an option in Angular as selected?

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

I have following code for my dropdown menu. How can I set a value as selected?

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <label class="input-group-text labelDropDown" for="inputGroupSelect01">Art der
    Integration</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" formControlName="integrationType">
    <option value="statisch">statisch</option>
    <option value="dynamisch">dynamisch</option>
    <option value="nein">nein</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I thought it will be selected if I type in the selected keyword? Why does angular not do this?

Comment: Also I tried the [selected] Angular form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 - Select default value in dropdown \[Reactive Forms\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011521/angular-4-select-default-value-in-dropdown-reactive-forms)

Answer (score 2):

I think this work for you:
Use `selected` in the `<option>` tag

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <label class="input-group-text labelDropDown" for="inputGroupSelect01">Art der
    Integration</label>
 <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" formControlName="integrationType">
     <option value="statisch">statisch</option>
     <option value="dynamisch">dynamisch</option>
     <option value="nein" selected>nein</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This wont be selected...

Comment: for="inputGroupSelect01">Sprach-Framework</label> <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" formControlName="languageForm"> <option selected *ngFor="let option of frameworkArray " (click)="getSelectdDropdown(frameworkArray.indexOf(option) +1, option); addNewItemFramework(frameworkArray.indexOf(option) +1);"> {{option}}</option> [selected]="option.selected

Answer (score 0):

The selected value is defined by the formControl you bound it to. Once you give the FormControl `integrationType` a value, this value will be selected. If you set `nein` as it's value, the 3rd option `nein`will be selected.

**Example edit value after init**

```
this.myFormGroup.get('integrationType').setValue('nein');
```

**Example with value on init**

```
this.myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      integrationType: ['nein'],
    });
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with code`?

Comment: the question is how do i get the selected value

Comment: I build my reactive forms with form builder

Comment: The selected value is whatever you will put instead of 'nein'. If you have an existing data, you read the value from this data and put this.

Comment: constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public sc: SoftwareComponentsService
  ) {
    {
      this.inputFormAllgInfo = _formBuilder.group({
        languageForm: ['', null],
        selectedLanguage: ['', null],
        copyRightInformationForm: ['', null],
        startUsageForm: ['', null],
        vendorForm: ['', null],
        versionForm: ['', null],
        statusForm: ['', null],
      });
    }
  }

Comment: I build it like this, but don´t know how i can set the value as selected

Comment: You told your select-Element, that the value of the select is bound to `integrationType` with `formControlName="integrationType"`. Whatever value is hold by this formcontrol gets automatically selected. I don't see that control in your formbuilder code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-khgfqr?file=src/app/app.component.html&view=editor

Comment: for="inputGroupSelect01">Sprach-Framework</label>
                        <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" formControlName="languageForm">
                            <option selected *ngFor="let option of frameworkArray "
                                (click)="getSelectdDropdown(frameworkArray.indexOf(option) +1, option); addNewItemFramework(frameworkArray.indexOf(option) +1);">
                                {{option}}</option>
                            [selected]="option.selected"

Comment: There is so much wrong in that stackblitz, can't get it to work. You miss importing reactive form, you are not calling the getFramework function (you just name it), also the url doesn't work for me. If you want the first framework to be selected, then set the value of `frameworkArray[0]` to it

Comment: I call it in the constructor

Comment: No, you name it, you don't call it. Calling a function would require `()`

Comment: [selected]="frameworkArray[0]" does not work for me

Comment: You still don't get it. Leave out the selected attribute, **it doesn't matter here** It only matters which value is hold by the **formControl** related to the select element.

Comment: can you make a example on stackblizz?

Comment: I dont get it..

Answer (score 0):

Selected is an boolean parameter from the HTML Element select
so you have set it to true for the specific option element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Alternative Solutions:
use selectedHTMLEl.selectedIndex

sets the selected Option by the Index of Option

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-khgfqr?file=src/app/app.component.html&view=editor

Comment: for="inputGroupSelect01">Sprach-Framework</label> <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" formControlName="languageForm"> <option selected *ngFor="let option of frameworkArray " (click)="getSelectdDropdown(frameworkArray.indexOf(option) +1, option); addNewItemFramework(frameworkArray.indexOf(option) +1);"> {{option}}</option> [selected]="option.selected