# Angular 5 autoFill form Keyup vs keydown vs keypress

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am using reactive form and I have section there where I want to populate values into another field

now for some reason when I use saved values from the browser it does not fill the email completely. it only takes first letter of the email and this happens sometimes when I fill the email form manually.

here is the live example of my code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5l9kb4

Comment: try using `property binding` `[value]="myForm.get('email').value"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated

```
fillForm() {
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    //I'm using .controls and .get, but both work here. Pick the one you prefer
    this.myForm.controls['second_phone'].setValue(value.phone, { emitEvent: false});
    this.myForm.get('second_email').setValue(value.email, { emitEvent: false});
  });
}
```

*You can also use `{ onlySelf: true }` in the `setValue` if needed (Ref:
[Angular 2 - FormControl setValue 'onlySelf' parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602837/angular-2-formcontrol-setvalue-onlyself-parameter))*

and remove:  `value="{{myForm.get('email').value}}"` from your secondary fields in your templates.

---

*Not the best approach*

Try this:

```
fillForm() {
    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if ((!value.second_email && value.email) || (!value.second_phone && value.phone)) {
          value.second_phone = value.phone;
          value.second_email = value.email;
      } 
    });
  }
```

Comment: Aight, I actually took advantage of the fact that you used  `value="{{myForm.get('email').value}}"` in your template for your secondary field. Because I never actually set the value of your secondary fields, it works with your if statement. But now that I think of it, I realized it's pretty messy and bad practice. I updated the solution with a better approach that more logical

Comment: thanks it works now! but do you have another recommendation I am trying to come up with best practice

Comment: perfect! wish I could vote your answer multiple times

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)